# Should diskutil list an unmounted drive?

Tags: diskutil

`diskutil list` showed the presence of an external drive.  But nether Finder nor `df` showed it.  And there was no "oops" pop-up when I unplugged it.

Is `diskutil list` supposed to show everything plugged in even if not mounted?

Comment: add the contents of diskutil list to your original question, that may help...

Answer (score 2):

From the manual page `diskutil` for the `list` *verb*:

> List disks, including internal and external disks, whole disks and partitions, and various kinds of virtual or offline disks.

So, yes it should list all disks, even if not mounted.

Note however, if you've ejected the disk instead of un-mounting it, it will not appear when using `diskutil list`. Also, once a disk have been un-mounted, it will not cause a flag to be raise as if pulling out a USB flash drive while still mounted, when disconnecting the un-mounted disk.

Comment: "ejected the disk instead of un-mounting" — hmmm.  I clicked the eject icon in Finder which gives a pop-up about ejecting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `diskutil list` is the similar command of `fdisk -l` on linux (mac also have `fdisk` command, but it is different thing), which shows all connected (or virtual) disks including not mounted.

When you buy new HDD, it may not have the partitions yet, but you can check the total size of disk, identifiers, or status by using commands like `diskutil list`. And also you can check partition tables and how it is mounted. These commands are very useful when you manually create partitions or format drives.